# css transform height not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to animate the height property of an element and for some reason it isn't animating at all.

[**Here's the fiddle where I'm trying to animate.**](http://jsfiddle.net/uJCQV/)

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        li 1
    </li>
    <li>
        li 2
    </li>
    <li>
        li 3
    </li>
</ul>​
```

Css

```
ul.hide {
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

JS:

```
setTimeout(function () { $('ul').addClass('hide'); }, 2000);
setTimeout(function () { $('ul').removeClass('hide'); }, 4000);​
```

Is there something I'm missing or forgetting about?

Comment: you're adding `display: none`

Comment: what are you trying to do? are you trying to get the UL to slowly lose height as it disappears?

Comment: @Nile pretty much, I'm trying to do the equivalent of jquery's `slideToggle()` in css3 transitions.

Comment: well when you add `display: none` it completely makes the element disappear... use `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: @Nile I never added display none

Comment: @qwertymk Why don't you want to use `slideToggle` but you use jQuery in order to get the element? Are you using jQuery or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/css-transition-height-0-to-height-auto

Comment: @Oriol No, I'm just using it in the fiddle for demo purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can animate `height` if it's automatic, ie if you're not setting it explicitly. Just try adding `height: 50px;` to `ul` in your fiddle.

Use `transform: scaleY(0);` instead!

Answer (score 1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/uJCQV/1/

You can use

```
$('ul').css('height',$('ul').height())
setTimeout(function () {$('ul').addClass('hide');}, 2000);
setTimeout(function () { $('ul').removeClass('hide'); }, 4000);
```

Or you can also use `max-height`:

```
ul.hide {
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul{max-height:999px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uJCQV/2/